# Ajustar tamaño de un Frame a la ventana principal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Ya llevo rato utilizando la librería PyQt5 de Python y ya he llegado a hacer buenas interfaces gráficas pero hay algo que de momento no he podido hacer y es que el Frame(QFrame) se ajuste automáticamente a las dimensiones de la ventana raíz (QMainWindow) sin necesidad de darle dimensiones al Frame.

Answer (score 3):

Asigna un [`Layout`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/layout.html) al widget central de tu ventana, por ejemplo un `QVBoxLayout`:

```
import sys

#from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class TestApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(770, 627)
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame y Layout")

        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.vertical_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.vertical_layout.setSizeConstraint(
            QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint
            )
        self.vertical_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.central_widget)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(u"background-color:aqua;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas sencilla que encontre de hacerlo es:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Main_App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        contenedor = QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(contenedor) # Fusiona el contenedor con la raiz
        contenedor.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightblue;")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])
    window = Main_App()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```